# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem when using 'fetch' in a consultation, which is responsible for redeeming a PPA and, from it, its programs, which in turn, redeem shares, and for this reason fetch is used. When fetch is not used, the query works normally, but, due to the above needs, it is necessary.

Method with a query:

```
public PPA localizarPPACompleta(Long idPpa) {
        String sql = "SELECT a FROM br.gov.ac.tce.icuria.modelo.entidades.planejamento.PPA a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.programas AS p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.acoes WHERE a.id = :idPpa";

        TypedQuery<PPA> query = entityManager.createQuery(sql, PPA.class);
        query.setParameter("idPpa", idPpa);

        try {
            return query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException ne) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

PPA class mapping:

```
@EntidadeDoPlanejamento
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder = {})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity(name = "br.gov.ac.tce.icuria.modelo.entidades.planejamento.PPA")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "ID_PPA"))
@Table(name = "PPA", schema = "planejamento", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "UQ__PPA_1", columnNames = { "ID_ENTIDADE",
                "ANO_INICIAL_VIGENCIA", "ANO_FINAL_VIGENCIA" }),
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "UQ__PPA_2", columnNames = { "NUMERO_LEI",
                "ID_ENTIDADE" }) })
@NamedQuery(name = "PPA.porChaveLogica", query = "select p from br.gov.ac.tce.icuria.modelo.entidades.planejamento.PPA p where p.ano = :ano and p.entidade = :entidade")
@Audited(auditParents = Cadastravel.class)
public class PPA extends Cadastravel implements IFDadosElegis {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3581419763803965106L;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NUMERO_LEI", nullable = false)
    private Integer numero;

    @CampoValidacao
    @CampoChave
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ANO_LEI", nullable = false)
    private Integer ano;

    @CampoValidacao
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ANO_INICIAL_VIGENCIA", nullable = false)
    private Integer anoInicialDeVigencia;

    @CampoValidacao
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ANO_FINAL_VIGENCIA", nullable = false)
    private Integer anoFinalDeVigencia;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "TIPO_LEI", nullable = false)
    private TipoDaLei tipoDaLei;

    @XmlTransient
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ppa")
    private Set<Programa> programas;

    @XmlTransient
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ppa")
    private Set<LDO> ldos;

    @XmlTransient
    @Column(name = "CAMINHO_DOCUMENTO_ELEGIS", nullable = true)
    private String caminhoDocumentoNoElegis;
    
    @XmlTransient
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ppa")
    private Set<Orgao> orgaos;
```

Console error:

```
17:04:10,249 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-10) SQL Error: 207, SQLState: S0001
17:04:10,249 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-10) Nome de coluna 'br' inválido.
17:04:10,249 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] (default task-10) HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
17:04:10,249 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-10) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1514)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1553)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TypedQueryNonTxInvocationDetacher.getSingleResult(TypedQueryNonTxInvocationDetacher.java:69)
    at br.gov.ac.tce.icuria.persistencia.dao.PpaDAO.localizarPPACompleta(PpaDAO.java:39)
    at br.gov.icuria.service.PPAService.localizarPPACompleta(PPAService.java:53)
    at br.gov.icuria.service.PPAService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.localizarPPACompleta(Unknown Source)
    at br.gov.icuria.conversor.PpaConverter.getIdentificavel(PpaConverter.java:21)
    at br.gov.icuria.conversor.PpaConverter.getIdentificavel(PpaConverter.java:10)
    at br.gov.icuria.conversor.ConversorGenerico.getAsObject(ConversorGenerico.java:23)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:147)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectOneValue(MenuRenderer.java:146)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:80)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1105)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:1006)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1317)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:733)
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectOne.processValidators(UISelectOne.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:921)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:921)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:921)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:921)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:921)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel.processValidators(Panel.java:313)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:921)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.Fieldset.processValidators(Fieldset.java:225)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:608)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:159)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:365)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:261)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1307)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:53)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at br.gov.icuria.filter.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at br.gov.icuria.filter.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:419)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4273)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1257)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1140)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1151)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1010)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Nome de coluna 'br' inválido.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:602)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:524)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7375)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3206)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:247)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:222)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:446)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 132 more
```

I am using the hibernate version 5.0.0.Final

Comment: I have a guess, that `Nome de coluna 'br' inválido` can tell you something. And just a sidenote: you are doing extremely bad thing that you are coding in some X language.. which is not English.

Comment: The main problem is that 'br' is not a column, it is a package, but for some reason, when making the query, it is treated as a column.

Answer (score 0):

Entity should be specified without package

```
String sql = "SELECT a FROM PPA a ...
```